# How to get in script tag of vue file of / pages / when using Nuxt.js and nuxt-i18n

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-i18n, nuxt-i18n

https://qiita.com/munieru_jp/items/d7e9f98b5ab5960e7a93

If you do as above, you can get the contents of `{{$ t ('HELLO_WORLD')}}` in the `<template>` tag.
How can I get `{{$ t ('HELLO_WORLD')}}` in the `<script>` tag in the same file?

The reason is that I want to manage **title descriptions** and **og** related items with head.

We apologize for the inconvenience, but we would appreciate it if you could teach us.
Then thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have access to the nuxt-i18n translation helper in the script of your page with `this.$t` and the `head` method on the other hand has access to the `this` context.
So you could do something like this:

```
export default {
    head () {
        return {
            title: this.$t('HELLO_WORLD')
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `head` method to set the HTML Head tags for the current page.

https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-head/